# How do I populate an Excel userform combobox with fields from a pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, userform

The users don't want to look at the spreadsheets or pivot table they want a form to choose what they want and print a report.

I have a userform that has 3 combo boxes (Provider, Year, & Quarter). When the user chooses what they need it will filter the data from the pivot table so they can print a report. I haven't managed to populate the userform comboboxes with the pivot table fields.

I have tried putting the fields I want to filter in column section and filter section and couldn't get it to work. From another suggestion I put the sections I want in the filtered sections then renamed the cell they were in on the pivot table and that didn't work either.

The only thing that sort of worked was putting them in filtered area then going to RowSource in Properties and putting the name of the cell, but it didn't show all the list only "All". Right now I have in the row section Provider & Name, in the column section I have Year, Quarter & Values.

Pivot table
[image]

I don't know if it isn't working because the userform is accessed from a command button on another userform or if it is the way I have the pivot table set up. I am using Excel 2016.

This is my latest attempt at the code.

```
Sub FillcboProviderPT()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ComReportPT")
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables("ptComReport")
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Provider").LabelRange.Select

    Dim Item As PivotItem
    Dim index As Integer
    index = 1

    For Each Item In pf.PivotItems
        Me.cboProviderPT.AddItem Item.Name
    Next Item

    Me.cboProviderPT.AddItem "(All)"
End Sub

Private Sub cboProviderPT_Change()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ComReportPT")
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables("ptComReport")
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Provider").LabelRange.Select

    pf.CurrentPage = Me.cboProviderPT.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: we can help you so much better if you provide your coding attempts and what is not working about them. as written this is very vague and any attempts to help may create more confusion

Comment: Have you considered slicers?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I've never used slicers before so I'll have to read about them to see how to use them. Thank you for the suggestion.